# Magento 1.9 getting a blank page when creating a new product or edit old product

Tags: magento-1.9, new-products, product-edit

Magento 1.9 getting a blank page when creating a new product or edit a old product.

Here is the screenshot:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3223861/004f51987079007debc43adfe3537395

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. I have tried a lot of things like:

- disable compiler.
- flush cache.
- disable all extenstions.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your extensions related to products / product grid. Try enable all your custom extension(s) that you have recently disabled.

Comment: Thanks for reply

But I have disabled all extensions but nothing happen now I am again active all extensions.

Comment: Do did you activate your extensions, or do you work on it now?

Comment: yes i am working on it .

Comment: @VijayRana, do you have product sliders extension ?

Comment: yes i have product sliders extension

Comment: @VijayRana, That means i am thinking, you uninstalled that product sliders extension from your admin panel right?

Comment: But its by default in neoshop magento theme

Comment: @VijayRana, you have to enable that extension or complete remove from your root. Then only it will resolve

Comment: if I disable the extension from 
configration=> Advanced=>Disable Modules Output  than its work or need to remove with files ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` 
in  **index.php** file in your root?

Also try to activate all the extensions you recently disabled. Then you can disable one by one and check for the extension that is making trouble!

Comment: okay, i will do this solution.

Comment: I have disabled the module (configration=> Advanced=>Disable Modules Output) Now my site not working. Both frontend and backend show a blank screen.

Comment: Can I active that extension from the database.Any idea?

Comment: @VijayRana https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159152/12148 then delete your /var/cache folder

Comment: You can active modules from your magento folder in your FTP / SFTP.

magento_folder/app/etc/modules/

Then edit the files and edit from "false" to "true"